# Upgrade timeline of LTS to LTS and non LTS to LTS

Tags: upgrade

Not a problem, but have been seeing questions recently of people not being offered upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  I thought these upgrades were offered back in June.  I upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10 and this was offered back in May.  Imagine that different versions paths have different schedules, but google does not help explaining(that I found).  Does someone know the schedules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every release has it's schedule published a few days into the development cycle, eg. Ubuntu 20.04's release schedule https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule was created on 2019-February-19, though was just a place holder until 2019-October-17 when development started.  The LTS to LTS occur **after** the 20.04.1 in all ML & official documentation, without a more precise definition of what *after* means (but do you need it?)

After a release reaches EOL the `archive.ubuntu.com` will be moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Again the word is **after**, for 17.04 this occurred the following day-week (mirrors of course don't all clear out the same time..) but for most releases there is a far longer delay (*17.04 was unusually quick*).

Comment: Watching the bugs of users who forced the install being filed (Official documentation on how to force the upgrade early was released soon after 20.04's release) gives a clue on problems users encounter (note made easy this cycle with python2 & Qt4 reaching EOL...) but there will also be issues. A lot of discussions are done in public, however not all are.

Comment: On the schedule you'll also note dates don't currently exist for each point release yet for *focal*, it's a living document that changes over time, the history of it though can be read (ie. public on wiki).  Future releases though are likely to be on discourse (which isn't as public)

Comment: Thanks.  I was under the impression that a XX.04.01 release happened in about June(older releases maybe) and that upgrade paths open soon after.  That was why I was puzzled that people were not seeing upgrade paths yet in their questions of the last few days.

Comment: Both 20.04.1 & 18.04.5 were delayed, refer https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2020-June/004980.html  (*I know I posted it places, but can't currently find it as it was awhile ago; I know it was covered in UWN https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue636 but it was elsewhere too in Ubuntu News*)